# Understanding the concepts of OOP

Tags: php, oop, object, object-oriented-analysis

Apologies for the potentially super simple question. I am trying to understand OOP. I have gone through tutorials but many of them are hyper simplified and by giving myself a 'real' project I am hitting obstacles most tutorials don't seem to cover. Heres a scenario I kind of wish to understand:

If I was making a very basic sports game (think Fifa) I currently have 3 objects:

- Object of Pitch
- Object of Team
- Object of Player

I am hitting my first wall of understanding because I don't want player to simply be an extension of team. After all in real life we would all be objects of human with an attribute that tells us which team we belong to before we are a sub object of a team.

What is the best practise for this?

Should I be:

1. Creating the objects of player and then adding each object to an array which is stored against the team object? This is how I would do it procedurally.
2. Storing the team against the player.
3. Storing the player against the team.
4. Extending player by team (I want to avoid this unless its actually the done thing)

This is just a brain exercise right now so I don't really have code but

```
$team1 = new teamObject('red');

$player1 = new players('John'); 
$team1->addToTeam($player1);
```

This strikes me as it wouldn't work because in the teamObject Class I wouldn't be able to call any of the Player classes function on the passed player function?

Comment: Of course you can call player methods if they're in a team.  OOP would be pretty useless if you couldn't have objects that contained other objects.  In fact, this kind of thing - composing objects - should be favored over creating inheritance hierarchies.  You (and, really, all programmers learning OOP for the first time) should read this book: https://smile.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1548616841&sr=8-2&keywords=gang+of+four  It teaches the general methodology of how to think about OOP, with multiple examples.

Answer (score 1):

This generally makes sense to me:

```
$team1 = new teamObject('red');
$player1 = new players('John'); 
$team1->addToTeam($player1);
```

Although typically it would probably look more like this (but it's really the same thing):

```
$team1 = new Team('red');
$player1 = new Player('John'); 
$team1->addPlayer($player1);
```

> This strikes me as it wouldn't work because in the teamObject Class I wouldn't be able to call any of the Player classes function on the passed player function?

You certainly can call Player functions, because after adding the player to the team, the team will have a reference to the player(s). It can simply call player functions via that reference. A function in the team might use:

```
$this->players[0]->pretendToBeHurt();
```

You absolutely don't want to extend Team in this scenario.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, can you point me at any documentation/ provide a deeper example of calling an objects function from another class? I cant seem to wrap my head around it!

Comment: @SqlQuery123 here's an example: https://gist.github.com/evert/8e1d9b2d5a97c4e69712af802afba707

Comment: Another way to think about it is that you are not calling a function from another class, you are calling a function on an *object*. The team must have a reference to that object, typically in a property.

Comment: Evert, that is incredibly useful! Thank you so much for putting together a practical example! It is really clear and makes sense! It is good to know I can pass objects in that manner too! What is the best way to provide thanks on this site? I have upvoted your answer!

Comment: Apologies Evert, are objects always stored as an array or can you store the object directly in a variable?

Comment: @SqlQuery123 in the case of a team there are many players, so you need an array. In a case where there is a 1:1 association you would use a direct property. It really comes down to: if you need more than 1 of a thing, you need an array.

Comment: Hi @Evert, I think I am struggling to get my head around the syntax of the 1:1 association. I have posted that as a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392844/php-oop-syntax-when-working-with-objects-of-another-class, would it be possible to ask for you to take a look?

Comment: @SqlQuery123 you're struggling with stuff that are very much basics. I think you're better off using a good tutorial, book or other resource than to try and deduce how PHP works through trial and error and stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

In my experience many beginners make mistakes by being afraid of having too many classes. They try to use inheritance to somehow "save space" and end up with nonsensical object representations.

You are right to assume that a Player is not an extension of Team. Those are 2 different entities so thats a no to approach 4.

The way that these data structures will be held within each other really depends on the actual implementation and the data-model. I don't know how familiar you are with databases and data models but what we have here is a *many-to-many relationship*: a team has many players and a player can (in the course of his career) belong to multiple teams.

How you implement this relationship in PHP objects is then just the matter of how you want to *use* it. You will also find that often these objects are held in both places, using both your approaches 2 and 3.

- Will you need to work with all the players in a team? Have an array of players stored in the Team object.
- Will you need a list of all the teams in the player's career? Have an array of teams in the Player object.
- Will you need the current team of a player? Have a single Team object in Player.
- Will you need the Player who is the team captain? Have a single Player object in Team.
- etc.

And yes, then you would have methods like:

```php
$player->addToTeam($team1);

$team->addPlayer($player);

$team->addPlayers([
    $player1,
    $player2
]);
```

(As a side-note, have a look at PSR coding standards, name your classes capitalized and in singular form: `Player`, `Team`, `Pitch`. Reading through the document as soon as possible pays off.)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much and I will certainly have a read of the PSR coding standards! 

As this is a hypothetical program and I don't have clear requirements for myself, am I correct in thinking then that as this is a many to many relationship I am best off retaining team as a attribute of player and vice versa so down the line I can pull any information I need?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Sometimes you may need `teams` property within a `Player` object, other times `players` property within a `Team` object. But the problem gets more complicated here. You want to prevent a situation when in the `Player` you have a reference to a specific team, but in the referenced `Team` you have no knowledge of this player. Which do you believe then? You will find that you need some *universal source of truth* - a single place to store the data. That can be the *model* (the database access layer) or for instance a *service*.

Comment: In the end you don't actually store the referenced objects within each other (except to cache - optimize performance). You just provide methods like `$team->getPlayers()` which in turn asks the *service* for the right data. And when you call `$player->getTeams()` it asks the same service which taps into the same data and you don't have any discrepancy.